# How can I check if ECC Key and Public Key are being passed through Js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, messaging, pubnub

I'm having a problem locating where my problem is. I'm using PubNub for realtime messaging and the example project is using ECC (elliptical curve cryptography) encrypted messaging.

Every thing in the file works(animation, channel presence, etc.) except for sending the message. Every time I hit send I get this message:

Here is my chat-app.js file:

```
(function() {

  if (typeof(user) === 'undefined') {
    return;
  } 

  var output = document.getElementById('output'), 
      input = document.getElementById('input'), 
      picture = document.getElementById('picture'),
      presence = document.getElementById('presence'),
      action = document.getElementById('action'),
      send = document.getElementById('send');

  var channel = 'fun';

  var keysCache = {};

  var pubnub = PUBNUB.init({
      subscribe_key: 'sub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      publish_key: 'pub-c-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
      uuid: user.name,
      auth_key: user.gtoken,
      ssl: true
  });


  function displayOutput(message) {
    if(!message) return;
    if(typeof(message.text) === 'undefined') return;

    var html = '';

    if ('userid' in message && message.userid in keysCache) {

      var signature = message.signature;

      delete message.signature;

      var result = ecc.verify(keysCache[message.userid].publicKey, signature, JSON.stringify(message));

      if(result) {
        html = '<p><img src="'+ keysCache[message.userid].picture +'" class="avatar"><strong>' +  keysCache[message.userid].name + '</strong><br><span>' + message.text + '</span></p>';
      } else {
        html = '<p><img src="images/troll.png" class="avatar"><strong></strong><br><em>A troll tried to spoof '+ keysCache[message.userid].name +' (but failed).</em></p>';
      } 

      output.innerHTML = html + output.innerHTML;

    } else {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', '/user/' + message.userid, true);
      xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
          var res = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

          keysCache[message.userid] = {
            'publicKey': res.publicKey,
            'name': res.name,
            'artist': res.artist,
            'picture': res.picture,
            'id': res.id
          }
          displayOutput(message);
        }
      };
      xhr.send(null); 
    }
  }

  function getHistory() {
    pubnub.history({
      channel: channel,
      count: 30,
      callback: function(messages) {
        messages[0].forEach(function(m){ 
          displayOutput(m);
        });
      }
    });
  }

  pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: channel,
    restore: true,
    connect: getHistory,
    disconnect: function(res){
      console.log('disconnect called');
    },
    reconnect: function(res){
      console.log('reconnecting to pubnub');
    },
    callback: function(m) {
      displayOutput(m);
    },
    presence: function(m){
      if(m.occupancy === 1) {
        presence.textContent = m.occupancy + ' person online';
      } else {
        presence.textContent = m.occupancy + ' people online';
      }
      if((m.action === 'join') || (m.action === 'timeout') || (m.action === 'leave')){
        var status = (m.action === 'join') ? 'joined' : 'left';
        action.textContent = m.uuid + ' ' + status +' room';
        action.classList.add(m.action);
        action.classList.add('poof');
        action.addEventListener('animationend', function(){action.className='';}, false);
      }
    }
  });

  function post() {
    var safeText = input.value.replace(/\&/g, '&amp;').replace( /</g,  '&lt;').replace(/>/g,  '&gt;');
    var message = { text: safeText, userid: user.id };

    var signature = ecc.sign(user.eccKey, JSON.stringify(message));
    message['signature'] = signature;

    pubnub.publish({
      channel: channel,
      message: message
    });

    input.value = '';
  }

  input.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    if(input.value === '') return;
    (e.keyCode || e.charCode) === 13 && post();
  }, false);

  send.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(input.value === '') return;
    post();
  }, false);


})();
```

This error is coming from my ecc.js file

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined
```

However, I'm assuming the error is in the chat-app.js file because I didn't touch the ecc.js file. I got it from the project -- https://github.com/pubnub/auth-chat-demo

More info on ECC can be found here: https://github.com/jpillora/eccjs

Comment: So what is your actual problem?

Comment: @zerkms I'm trying to figure out why I'm getting an error (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'r' of undefined )

Comment: If the error is coming from ecc.js, then you should be able to identify what function is being called when that error is happening, and where within your code that that function is being called.  Provide this information to facilitate debugging.

Comment: Because you're trying to read property `r` of an `undefined` value.

Comment: @TheGreatContini Error happens when "send.addEventListener" from chat-app.js is clicked.  I've been looking through the ecc.js file to find 'r' (https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpillora/eccjs/gh-pages/dist/0.3/ecc.js) it's just filled with algorithms that I can't make out. I will keep studying it, just wanted some help if anyone has run into something similar.

Comment: @ChāSkies: Just some quick pointers.  The code has a `curve.r` in the ECC, which must be the problem.  Look for example in the function `sjcl.ecc.basicKey.generateKeys`.  It is some property of the curve, and it looks to me like it might be the order of the base point on the curve.  You might do some reading on [ECDSA](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~koc/ccs130h/notes/ecdsa-cert.pdf) to understand this further.  See section 5.  Gotta run now, will try to have a closer look later

Comment: @TheGreatContini Thanks, I will keep trucking along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, it looks like this line is giving you the error:

```
var signature = ecc.sign(user.eccKey, JSON.stringify(message));
```

So I am guessing you are not properly passing user.eccKey?

Do you have all the user data from oAuth (or any login auth)? or is the eccKey generated correctly upon the user sign-up?

Also, try include the non-minified version of ecc.js so you can track where the error is coming from more easily.
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jpillora/eccjs/gh-pages/dist/0.3/ecc.js

Comment: I'm using google-oauth and I can see all of my database data stored in node-persist upon sign-up, but I assumed that the keys were being stored in PubNub history. I agree that the eccKey is not being handled correctly because I just tried to output it in the console and it's "undefined" after passport serialization. I will keep digging. I really appreciate this!

Comment: Yeah, you should store the key in a DB, so using node-persist should be fine! (Using PubNub History as a DB is not so good idea for real-life scenario! The original code on the repo is just a demo.).

Comment: Thanks problem solved! I just took out the DB pseudo channel and used my Mongo db instead.

Comment: @Chā how you did that can you please explain.